# data-id not generating unique values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to generate a data-id using mustache.js library. I am currently following a tutorial on youtube about APIs. In that tutorial tutor is able to generate the ids but I am not able to. My code is below. Iam trying to generate a button with the ids.

```
    let nameTemplate = "" + "<li>" + "<p>Name: {{name}}</p>" + 
    "<p>Position: {{position}}</p>" + "<button data-id= '{{id}}' 
   class='remove'>X</button>" + "</li>";
```

later I am using AJAX to delete that particular data which was shown. Here is my AJAX code.

```
      $displayUsers.delegate(".remove", "click", function(){
       $.ajax({
       type: "DELETE",
        url: "http://localhost/JS/REST%20API%20JSON/test.json" + 
        $(this).attr('data-id')

          });

          });
```

When I am debugging I am not able to see data-ids being generated it's just empty. and it's showing error in jquery file. Just showing red lines under the minified jquery file.
   Here is my HTML

```
    <ul id="displayUsers"></ul>
   Name: <input type="text" id="userName"> <br/><br/>
   Position: <input type="text" id="position"> <br><br/>
  <button id="addData">Add Data</button>
```

I am sorry if i was not being clear. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't generate the id for you.  It simply puts the id you have where the {{id}} token is.  Your id comes from the database.  In your router, you send the object to the view.  The view receives the object, which consists of name, etc.  Your object should have an id property.  Maybe it uses _id, instead.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Thanks for clarifying. I inserted some ids in my JSON so it'll work but I am still getting error in my jquery compressed file. Can you please help me out?